# Is it faster to try and avoid UNIQUE violations when inserting into a PostgreSQL database with efcore, or to catch the resulting exception?

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql, ef-core-3.0

Assuming I have a UNIQUE constraint on a column in my postgresql database, is it more performant to query the database before attempting to insert a new value or is it acceptable to catch the thrown exception when the database rejects the query?

My assumption was that postgres will check for these violations faster than it takes for EF core to construct and execute a query + then run the insertion. Is this the case?

```cs
try
{
    // _dctx is my DbContext
    _dctx.SomeTable.Add(newEntity);
    await _dctx.SaveChangesAsync();
}
catch (DbUpdateException ex)
{
    if (ex.InnerException is PostgresException npgex && npgex.SqlState == PostgresErrorCodes.UniqueViolation)
    {
        // Reached only when the UNIQUE constraint was violated
    }
    throw; // How other exceptions are handled isn't relevant to the question
}
```

vs

```cs
try
{
    if (await _dctx.SomeTable.AnyAsync(x => x.UniqueProperty == hopefullyUniquePropertyValue))
    {
        // Handle duplicate insertion here
    }
    _dctx.SomeTable.Add(newEntity);
    await _dctx.SaveChangesAsync();
}
catch (DbUpdateException ex) {}
```

Since this will be done concurrently / over several instances of this service I'll still be expecting to get these exceptions occasionally, but the question is whether the overhead of the `AnyAsync()` call is going to be substantially greater than that of allowing the database + ORM to take care of it?

Comment: I think uniqueness check is responsibility of database, so I would only care about performance when you will have troubles, otherwise it seems to me as premature optimalization.

Comment: What percentage of them would you expect to be duplicates?

Comment: ps; you'd probably get better overall performance by not saving every iteration, but you do then have the problem that one failed entity would prevent insertion of the batch.

Comment: The unique values in this particular case would be user-controlled (usernames) so at a sufficient user-count it could be that many duplicates are attempted before a valid one is provided.

Batching would definitely be a good way of going about it if I didn't need UI to respond quickly in this case!

Comment: Unless you expect a substantial percentage of duplicates your opening sentence answers your question. You have a unique constraint let the DB do the checking, *it's going to anyway*. @CaiusJard is correct you'll get better performance not committing on each entity. I actually disagree that "one failed entity would prevent insertion of the batch" is a problem; it's a benefit. A batch is a single transaction and should live of die (be saved or discarded) as a whole; thus 1 save for the entire batch.

Comment: I was more thinking in the context of having a file containing a million records to load, and you do it in a loop where you save only every 100, EF will construct a statement like `insert into table(col1,col2) values ((@p1,@p2),(@p3,@p4)...(@p199,@p200))" and when just one in those 100 is existing, the statement will fail. To get it to work you will have to find the entity and detach it from the graph which might be difficult if the db doesn't say which one is duplicated/still might have to parse an exception message, or alternatively go again one at a time

Comment: You're right in that if the whole thing is just creating a single user but involves 20 insert statements then it will be a transactions that should behave atomically and it's then a benefit

Comment: Ps; if we are talking about a user registration system here, I really don't think it would matter which route, even if we are talking about millions of users signing up simultaneously on a website. Humans in the loop make things so slow that asking whether it would be faster or better experience to do an Any precheck vs unique violation catch is relatively moot

Comment: Pps; feel free to test it yourself; run a million iterations of inserting the same value in a loop and catching the exceptions. Then run a million query for a random value. You might find the latter a few seconds faster, say.. but then ask yourself how long will it take for a million users to sign up? Saving a few seconds of cpu time over 3 months; it's an optimization that will never even pay for the collective efforts of you, me and Belayer even discussing it :)

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I'll stick to the first option then- and benchmark it when I've got time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checking whether a row exists before inserting is definitely the worse option, for two reasons:

- You are executing two SQL commands: one query to check if the row exists, and another to insert a new one. This means two network roundtrips, two commands executed in the database... It's quite a lot heavier than a single insert.
- The database may have changed between your check and your insert, so you may get unique constraint violations in any case (which you're not checking in your sample above).

However, rather than discussing performance in theory, it's always far better to simply benchmark the two options (with something like [BenchmarkDotNet](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/)).

Comment: Beware of constraint violations when doing a _normal_ `INSERT`, because it can be bad for performance, dead tuples, autovacuum and storage. [This article on the AWS Database Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/hidden-dangers-of-duplicate-key-violations-in-postgresql-and-how-to-avoid-them/) explains how to avoid all the dangers with the help of a speculative insertion, i.e., `INSERT ... ON CONSTRAINT DO NOTHING` and handling the success/failure result.